# 4 conditional statement not trigger Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>P2,ISBLANK(N2)),"Overdue", "Not Due",IF(N2>P2,"Closed Late","Closed on Time"))
```

I am looking to have formula that check 4 statement.

first: open cases (target closed date =P2), if Today > P2 and N2 (Completed date) is blank, = Overdue otherwise Not due

and also check
for closed cases where N2 is not blank, and N2>P2 = Close Late otherwise Closed on Time.

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()>P2,ISBLANK(N2)),"Overdue", "Not Due",IF(N2>P2,"Closed Late","Closed on Time"))
```

doesnt work

Comment: What I see you have missed the `IF()` syntax wrongly, you could try : `=IF(AND(TODAY()<P2,ISBLANK(N2)), "Not Due", IF(AND(TODAY()>P2,ISBLANK(N2)),"Overdue", IF(N2>P2,"Closed Late","Closed on Time")))`

Comment: let me post the same as an answer.

Comment: Hold on @MayukhBhattacharya (a bit shorter) : `=IF(ISBLANK(N2),IF(TODAY()<P2,"Not Due", "Overdue"), IF(N2>P2, "Closed Late", "Closed On Time"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try: (Posted in answers as mentioned by OP it is working for them).

[image]

---

```
=IF(AND(TODAY()<P2,N2=""),"Not Due",
 IF(AND(TODAY()>P2,N2=""),"Overdue",
 IF(N2>P2,"Closed Late","Closed On Time")))
```

---

In the OP, **[IF()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)** Function was not correctly structured and was missing the arguments for one of the conditions.

---

Or, one could follow the formula suggested by **[Notus_Panda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19353309/notus-panda)**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N2),IF(TODAY()<P2,"Not Due", "Overdue"), IF(N2>P2, "Closed Late", "Closed On Time"))
```